# is there anything like robotium's solo.clickOnText in MonkeyTalk?

Tags: javascript, android, robotium, monkeytalk

does anyone know if there is a similar command to robotium's

solo.clickOnText  within MonkeyTalk?

or how to do the same with javascript?

thanks for your help.

Update:
I have found in monkeyTalk syntax - to tap on any component labeled "ok"

`View OK Tap`

but for some reason the script says it has run ok, but nothing happens on the app.

When I record the action with the recorder it uses the

`Table ITEM selectIndex 1`

with the same result.

This is a native Android app and the `solo.clickOnText` command works well with Robotium, but we were wanting to try MonkeyTalk as it is quicker to record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robotium now also supports recording http://robotium.com/

Comment: thanks Naveed, I had seen that - ideally I was looking for something that covered both IOS and Android - the one thing I really like about robotium is that it is blackbox - where MonkeyTalk you need to make changes to package. We are still trying different solutions to see what is workable. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: My suggestion would be to not use one recorder for both iOS and Android as most of the time they perform worse then the recorders that are specialised for only one platform.

Comment: I think you are right. Will use Robotium which seems to be very stable. And will carry on looking for IOS.